# Perl Cgi: How to popup confirm with password

Tags: perl, cgi

How to popup confirm with password (other password not same like ssh password), then execute with ssh?

#### Package

```
use CGI qw/:standard/;
use DBI;
use strict;
use Time::Local;
use Net::SSH2;
#use Term::ReadKey; < maybe?
```

#### Main Code

```
my $pw;
my $pws = "1234";

if ($lqcgi->param('sel_cl')){
    $selected_action = $lqcgi->param('sel_cl');
    print "Password: \n"; #How to popup confirm with password. I don't know!
    $pw = <STDIN>;
    chomp ($pw);
    if ($pw eq $pws){
        $ssh2->connect($host{$mxEnv}) or die $!;
        $ssh2->auth_password($usr{$mxEnv},$pwd{$mxEnv});
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't, web pages don't work like that. (Or rather, you probably can, just not this way).

Comment: @Sobrique What's your proposal?

Comment: You should start by learning how HTTP works, then how CGI works.

Comment: @choroba What do you want me complaints about learning how HTTP works? :-/ Why can't you give me a possible proposal?

Comment: Because what you're trying to do isn't possible the way you're trying to do it. We can only help you solving your programming problems. Your problem here isn't a programming problem, it's that you don't understand the technologies you're trying to put together.

Comment: It looks like you're submitting a form. Why not just collect the password with an `<input type="password">` field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even i had this problem, the solution i found is that! Maintaining .htaccess  file at my webserver  with following entries in the configuration file in webserver.

for more information go here
`https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html`

which will allow CGI script to pop up authentication pop up and authenticates again your LDAP if LDAP maintained or else you can use remote->user variable to get the user id and have it cross checked against an array or a file.

i hope this might help you.

-Shantesh